Why does a Jenkins param value that refs an env variable get eval'd before it's passed to my shell script in freestyle job, but not in pipeline job?
I am looking at porting a Jenkins non-pipeline job to pipeline.  I encountered the situation where, if a parameter value references an environment variable, such as "${HOME}/etc" then the parameter value gets evaluated (eval'd) and then passed to my shell script step as the post-evaluation value "/var/lib/jenkins/etc".
First of all, I wasn't expecting this evaluation to occur in the non-pipeline job and couldn't find documentation that this is supposed to happen.  Is this documented somewhere?
Second of all, given that this DOES happen, how do I duplicate the behavior in the pipeline version where the shell script is ran using the sh() command?  The Pipeline version gets the parameter avar2 with value ${HOME}/etc.  I haven't found an option where the evaluation can be done for me before running the shell script in a pipeline job.  It seems I have to code the script file to do the evaluation on any env variable that might need it.
In the pipeline job, I tried having the shell script specified immediately in the job as well as having the shell script specified in a file in the workspace.  I only demonstrate the first case where the shell script is specified immediately in the job here.
I created a Freestyle Job with two string params:
    Name:          avar1
    Default Value: avar1val

    Name:          avar2
    Default Value: ${HOME}/etc

and an "Execute shell" Build Step having the text:
    #!/bin/bash -e
    env | sort

Running this job gives job console text that looks like the following:
    Started by user X
    Running as SYSTEM
    Building on the built-in node in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jam
    [jam] $ /bin/bash -e /tmp/jenkins15623yadayada.sh
    avar1=avar1val
    avar2=/var/lib/jenkins/etc
    .
    .
    .
    Finished: SUCCESS

I then created a pipeline job invokes the same shell script using the sh command.  Its definition is:
Create a Pipeline Job with two string params:
    Name:          avar1
    Default Value: avar1val

    Name:          avar2
    Default Value: ${HOME}/etc

and the Pipeline definition "Pipeline script"
    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Hello') {
                steps {
                    sh '''#!/bin/bash -e
                    env | sort
                '''
                }
            }
        }
    }

Running this job includes this text in the Jenkins job  Console Output
    .
    .
    avar1=avar1val
    avar2=${HOME}/etc
    .
    .
    Finished: SUCCESS

This is on a linux jenkins v2.452.3 on java 11

The why part is easy to explain. Freestyle jobs run on a single machine, so ${HOME} can be expanded without ambiguity. If it should be expanded at all is a design choice and before your question I didn't know that it was expanded. Pipeline jobs can run on multiple machines, or even without an assigned agent, so parameters might have different values in different parts of the pipeline depending on what agent (if any) is assigned.
It is possible to replicate the freestyle job behaviour by expanding in Groovy first and in the shell next
sh "echo ${params.avar2}"

but I would advise against that. Double expansion is hard to reason about.
